# Client timeout in Gemfire logs

Tags: gemfire

​

I am currently in the process of trouble shooting Gemfire logs for client timeout:

​
Logs:​

```
​[warning 2018/06/11 23:45:05.685 CDT xxxxsrv01_instance_42404_cacheserver <ClientHealthMonitor Thread> tid=0x97] Server connection from [identity(xx.xx.xx.xx(5338:loner):33228:4cae4ef2,connection=2; port=33261] is terminated because its client timeout of 10,000 has expired.
```

Even increasing the ​"read-timeout" value in client pool config to 200000 gives "client time out of 200000 has expired".

Also noticed below logs:

```
xxxxx_myinstance_42404_cacheserver <Handshaker /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:42404 Thread 229> tid=0x2c29cc] Bridge server: failed accepting client connection  {0}
```

​Can you please help me on possible causes of the issue.

Regards,​

Rahul N.​

Comment: In investigating further it was found that connection thread crossed 300 from the time when issue started appearing. Checking further.

Comment: Connection threads are showing 300 eventhough no clients are connected. Checked by netstat that no clients are connected to gemfire cache server showing connection threads as 300